AttributeError: object has no attribute dataclass python3.11
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from datetime import datetime
from typing import List as PyList
import json

@dataclass
class metadata:
 docType:str

@dataclass
class spr:
 sprType:str

@dataclass
class nMI:
 idx:int

@dataclass
class bene:
 bid:int
 put:str

@dataclass
class ttd(metadata,spr,nMI):
 bn:list[bene]


json_str = '''{
  "docType":"abc",
  "sprType":"def",
  "idx":2,
  "bn":[{
     "bid":3, "put":"out"}]
}'''

def printMethod(t:metadata):
    print(t)

def printMethod1(t:spr):
    print(t)

def processMethod(t:ttd):
  printMethod(t.metadata) 
  printMethod1(t.spr)


data = json.loads(json_str)

t=ttd(**data)

print(t)
# this prints the dictionary correctly

# ttd(idx=2, sprType='def', docType='abc', bn=[{'bid': 3, 'put': 'out'}])

processMethod(t)


I am getting a json value and deserializing in to objects using dataclass. In processMethod I am getting this error AttributeError: 'ttd' object has no attribute 'metadata'. Any suggestions please. I wanted to store the values in separate objects for ease of processing. I am not really familiar with inheritance and dataclasses and this in python 3.11

What's the point of a dataclass with a single integer or string field? Just use an integer or a string. And your use case doesn't seem to need any inheritance, unless I'm missing something? (Also, please post the full stack trace as part of your [mre].)

Instead::
@dataclass
class ttd(metadata, spr,nMI):
 bn:list[bene]

use:
@dataclass
class Ttd:
    metadata: Metadata
    spr: Spr
    nmi: NMI
    bn: list[Bene]

Like this you can access your metadata instance from TTD class

Have you tried running the code with this change?

This did not work - since it gave this error "got an unexpected keyword argument 'docType'"

json_str = '''{
  "m":{
  "docType":"abc"
  },
 "s":{
   "sprType":"def"
},
"n":{
   "idx":2
},
    
  "bn":[{
     "bid":3, "put":"out"}]
}'''


@dataclass
class ttd():
    m: metadata
    s:spr,
    n:nMI
    bn: list['Bene']


I had to change my json and class this way.
